# C#-like named argument in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript

Is it possible to use named argument in javascript?

E.g.

> void method (int a, int b);
>
> method(a:1, b:2);

Comment: I'm assuming you mean in 'javascript".  jQuery is just a library.

Answer (score 13):

In javascript you could do this:

```
function method(foo) {
    // use foo.a and foo.b here    
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
method({ a: 1, b: 2 });
```

Comment: Can this be applied to the `method` I defined in my question above?

Comment: @Nam Gi VU, yes, that's the example I provided.

Comment: Oh, I mean, with the method already defined `method(int a, int b)` and we can changed it - e.g. use php's `.attr(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is 'no', but you can come to an approximation by using a single object with names properties/members as the argument to your functions.  See **[here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/namedfunction.shtml)** for more details.